# Eloquent ORM select other field based on FK

Tags: mysql, orm, foreign-keys, eloquent

I have the following two tables:

```
users
-name
-country_id

countries
-id
-name
```

I'm to use the Eloquent ORM and run the following query:

```
Select user.name, countries.name FROM users
LEFT JOIN countries ON users.country_id = countries.id
```

But i'm having trouble. How can i tell Eloquent to fetch a different field from the countries table?

What i have now is:

```
User::all();
```

But that gets me only the country_id

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (I think).

Now i'm doing

```
User::with('Country')->get()
```

which returns me all users with a country property matching the country object so i can do:

```
$user->country->name
```